# Поиск целевого окна в Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

Есть два приложения: одно консольное, другое графическое. Консольное приложение по запуску из командной строки принимает параметр, заданный в командной строке, и передает этот параметр в графическое приложение. Задумка следующая: при запуске консольного приложения найти целевое окно графического приложения и послать ему сообщение с параметром. Оба приложения на MFC + WinAPI.

Как найти целевое окно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант. При создании окна графического приложения выбрать уникальный класс или уникальное имя окна. В консольном приложении искать окно по классу или по имени. Нужные функции: `RegisterClass`, `CreateWindow` и `FindWindow`.